# App crashes after upgrade expo sdk from 30 to 31

Tags: react-native, expo

I have updated the SDK using [this instruction](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/). And I ran the app. The app shows this error in red screen:

> babelHelpers.readOnlyError is not a function. (In
>   ‘babelHelpers.readOnlyError(“newSize”)’, ‘babelHelpers.readOnlyError’
>   is undefined )

How can I solve this error? 
I tried clearing the yarn cache, installing yarn packages again but do not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [webpage](https://forums.expo.io/t/upgrade-to-expo-31-babel-7/17044/7) solving my problem.

---

Add the following in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

make the `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],

    "env": {
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-remove-console"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

1. Update .babelrc and package.json
2. Delete node_modules folder
3. Install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console, babel-preset-expo. Run yarn or npm.

Run expo clearing cache using expo start -c